# Can FCM work instead of GCM in Unity 3d Project for notification and If work then What plugin will be required

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to migrate with google cloud messaging to firebase cloud messaging but problem is that may it work in Unity.I read all documentation but there is no answer.